# Arguments not being supplied to service

Tags: symfony

My validator service is not being supplied to validator. I get an error:
"Warning: Missing argument 1 for My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustomValidator::__construct()..."

Here is my services.yml

```
// My\Bundle\Resources\config\services.yml
services:
    my.validator.service:
        class: My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustomValidator
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

Here is my validator class:

```
// My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustomValidator
namespace My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyCustomValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Here's my validation.yml

```
// My\Bundle\Resources\config\validation.yml
My\Bundle\Entity\Page:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustom: ~
```

Here's my Constraint class

```
namespace My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class MyCustom extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Something is wrong with "%string%".';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this) . 'Validator';
    }
}
```

I'd be very appreciative if someone could help me with this.

I've tried changing the argument name to "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" as well, but no luck.

Comment: How are you trying to use it?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't really go to that yet. I want to perform a query inside the validate function and add an error based on the result of the query. But I haven't even been able to get past the simplest part.

Comment: The config is correct. Does the error happen in a container class? Tried to clear cache?

Comment: check the doctrine unique entity constraint and how it is built(and defined in the doctrine bundle), you should use the manager registry instead of the entity manager directly.

Comment: Have you an annotation class, or how are you applying the validator to the entity? In which context you got this error?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've added my validation.yml and Constraint class. You can see that I'm applying it to an entity. And I have cleared the cache. I haven't tried it in a container class. I will try that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was my services.yml. Because the service is being used as a validator, I MUST use the validator.constraint_validator tag. This is in the documentation. Whoops!

```
services:
    my.validator.service:
        class: My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustomValidator
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: my_custom_alias}
```

I also need to override the Constraint classes validatedBy() method so that it returns the alias above, e.g.:

```
// My\Bundle\Validator\Constrains\MyCustom.php
public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'my_custom_alias';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the doctrine registry to your service and using that to retrieve an entity manager instance.

Change your constructor to this:

```
public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
{
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Then amend your service configuration to this:

```
// My\Bundle\Resources\config\services.yml
services:
    my.validator.service:
        class: My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustomValidator
        arguments: [ @doctrine ]
```

Now anytime you need to get an entity manager in `MyCustomValidator` you can do this

```
$em = $this->registry->getManager()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still get the same error that indicates none of my arguments are being passed to the constructor:

"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MyCustomValidator::__construct() must be an instance of "...", none given".

I'm missing something here. My validator is being registered as a service properly, it's just not receiving arguments for some reason? I'm not aware of any other setting that could cause this kind of behaviour.